# Can i store html content of webpage in storm crawler?

Tags: web-crawler, elasticsearch-5, stormcrawler

I am using [strom-crawler-elastic](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/tree/master/external/elasticsearch). I can able to see the fetched urls and status of those. Configuration change in ES_IndexInit.sh file gives only url,title, host, text. But can i store the entire html content with html tags ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ES IndexerBolt gets the content of pages from the ParseFilter but does not do anything with it. One option would be to modify the code so that it pulls the *content* field from the incoming tuples and indexes it.

Alternatively, you could implement a custom ParseFilter which would copy the content of the page into a metadata key value and configure that field to be indexed via *indexer.md.mapping* in the configuration file.

Either way, you'd need to modify ES_indexInit.sh so that the field in ES gets indexed and/or stored the way you want it.

.

Comment: How can we achieve this (storing html in ES) in stormcrawler v1.15? 
Do we need to modify `parsefilters.json` and `ES_IndexInit.sh` only? Can you please highlight changes required. Thanks