# how to store content and page description to ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, web-crawler, stormcrawler

I am able to fetch and store page urls to elasticsearch, but i have a requirement i have to store page title,desctiption and content also ES. I am sure this is possible but need more clar
iication on IndexerBolt.java and ES_IndexInit.sh because i am able to print content of page in indexerBolt but failing to map the content to correct field to update to ES. I saw post
[Can i store html content of webpage in storm crawler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47626395/can-i-store-html-content-of-webpage-in-storm-crawler/47630147#47630147) related to same but not able to understand how it works. Can somebody provide me an example or sudo how can we do this.

I tried below but no luck. 
**ES_IndexInit.sh**

```
curl $ESCREDENTIALS -s -XPUT $ESHOST/status -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '
{
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "number_of_shards": 10,
            "number_of_replicas": 1,
            "refresh_interval": "5s"
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "status": {
            "dynamic_templates": [{
                "metadata": {
                    "path_match": "metadata.*",
                    "match_mapping_type": "string",
                    "mapping": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            }],
            "_source": {
                "enabled": true
            },
            "properties": {
                "nextFetchDate": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "dateOptionalTime"
                },
                "status": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "url": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                **"content": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                }**
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

**IndexerBolt.java**

```
public void execute(Tuple tuple) {

        String url = tuple.getStringByField("url");

        // Distinguish the value used for indexing
        // from the one used for the status
        String normalisedurl = valueForURL(tuple);
 System.out.println("************************header::***********"+tuple.toString());
            System.out.println("************************content ::***********"+tuple.getStringByField("text"));
        Metadata metadata = (Metadata) tuple.getValueByField("metadata");
        String text = tuple.getStringByField("text");
        **String content = tuple.getStringByField("text");**
        boolean keep = filterDocument(metadata);
        if (!keep) {
            eventCounter.scope("Filtered").incrBy(1);
            // treat it as successfully processed even if
            // we do not index it
            _collector.emit(StatusStreamName, tuple, new Values(url, metadata,
                    Status.FETCHED));

            **_collector.emit(StatusStreamName, tuple, new Values(content, metadata,
                    Status.FETCHED));**

            _collector.ack(tuple);
            return;
        }
```

--
Thank you very much in advance.
Regards,
Madhava

Comment: It works fine in ES 7.1 with StormCrawler 1.15 but content will not get update to ES when we use ES 6.5 and stormcrawler 1.12. Any body has done in same with ES 6.5? Please let me know what is the configutation i am missing. thanks

Comment: I am trying to do same example on ES 6.5, but it is having some issue in updating content to ES. my carwler is able to FETCH and update to status indices but content indices is empty. Is it possible to have this in ES 6.5 and its compatible version of Storm crawler is 1.12 i guess. kindly let me know if this is possible or not? thanks

Answer (score 1):

This IndexerBolt does not index the documents to Elasticsearch, it is used for debugging and sends the content to the console. [The one you want](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/external/elasticsearch/src/main/java/com/digitalpebble/stormcrawler/elasticsearch/bolt/IndexerBolt.java) is in the ES module.

The part of the schema you copied deals with the **status** of the URLs, not their content. BTW you definitely don't want to index the content field as *keywords*.

You'll need to change the mapping for the *content* index, [add store true to the content field](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/1.15/external/elasticsearch/ES_IndexInit.sh#L144), see also [ES documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-store.html).

The [video tutorial](https://youtu.be/KTerugU12TY) for SC 1.5 is a bit dated but should help you understand the basics.